# Создание WORD-документа с помощью php

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно наполнить таблицу WORD`овского документа имеющимся массивом.

**WORD`овская таблица:**

[image]

**Сформированный массив:**

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (
            [ID] = 29
            [NAME] = Блуза, Valeria Lux
            [PRODUCT_ID] = 27
            [QUANTITY] = 1.00
            [PRICE] = 2061.00
            [WEIGHT] = 42; 
        )

    [1] = Array
        (
            [ID] = 28
            [NAME] = Блузка, Stets
            [PRODUCT_ID] = 23
            [QUANTITY] = 1.0
            [PRICE] = 2345.00
            [WEIGHT] = 41; 
        )

)
```

Т.е. на выходе получить WORD`овский документ со значениями в таблице из массива.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/281376/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна полноценная работа именно с вордовскими форматами, то под Windows можно использовать COM:

```
$doc = new COM("word.application");
```

Соответственно, методы смотреть в документации по COM-объекту word.application.

Но для простых задач типа "вывести таблицу" этого вообще не нужно: офис прекрасно понимает HTML.

Comment: @klopp а если веб-сервер на Linux?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/138666/

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробовал считывать содержимое через file_get_contents и выполнять замену, только вот почему-то замена не происходит.

Comment: Естественно не проходит, это же сложный формат, со своими прибабахами. Описание потрохов того же doc - это около 300 страниц техдокументации, и это только если не касаться расширенных возможностей типа object embedding... С более современными docx чуть проще, но всё равно не настолько, чтобы работать как с простым текстом :)

Comment: @klopp, получилось только в том случае, если file_get_contents`у передать файл не DOC, а RTF :)

Comment: RTF - это тоже не "просто текст". В одном случае получится, в другом нет... Впрочем, каждый сам себе проблемы ищет :)